# Problem with the 74160 decade counter

Tags: digital-logic

I am experimenting with different TTL components and am having a lot of trouble with the [74160 decade counter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74160.pdf). I don't know if it's my inexperience or if I'm dealing with a malfunctioning IC, but the IC isn't doing what it's supposed to, and it heats up pretty darn fast (I always check for heating once I power up)

After some testing, I noted that all I have to do is connect the GND to ground and the +5V pin to 5V and it starts heating up fast. If I add a resistor connecting to ground, it doesn't heat up, but it heats up once I connect the remaining pins (as it stands, pins 7 and 8 are grounded, 9 and 16 are in +5). As soon as I power it up, all the outpins turn HIGH.

So here is what I'm wondering:

1. Do I ever need a resistor once a TTL datasheet tells me to connect such and such pins to ground or to +5V or can I connect them directly?
2. Can I conclude that my 74160 is short-circuited/malfunctioning?
3. Is there anything else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please check whether you have the correct pin-outs for the IC, and whether you have it connected the right way around. Not specific to this IC, but some ICs have multiple sources, and on rare occasions there will be conflicting datasheets / pin-outs.

Comment: I've done that, I've checked a TON of times the pins, and it is still no good. Would it help if I took a picture of how I wired it up?

Comment: @triplebig, a diagram would be good, but probably add one as it was originally connected. It sounds like you've fried the part so main thing is to make sure your replacement doesn't go the same way. Resistors shouldn't be needed but have you double-checked your supply is actually 5V and nothing else has been shorted?

Comment: It seems I must have fried the device at some point... The terminals were in short for some reason, and when I tried using a new 74160 it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the datasheet, the part normally pulls 60-70mA at 5V, dissipates 350mW.  This will be warm to the touch, not hot. Not sure why you're using an old TTL device, newer fast CMOS parts have standby currents in the 100uA range.

You mention adding a resistor to gnd, what's the other end of the resistor connected to?

You may float TTL inputs, hopefully there are no DC loads on the outputs, otherwise the chip will draw current unnecessarily.

Try this: connect a series resistor (5 ohms) inline with Vcc.  If you get a voltage drop > 0.5V across the resistor, then either the chip is damaged or the outputs (including RCO) are driving heavy loads.